# How to identify which Azure training model to use with Azure form recognizer service. Can multiple layouts be trained in the same model?

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services, azure-form-recognizer

I have been using the form recognizer service and form labeller tool, using the version 2 of the api, to train my models to read a set of forms. But i have the need to use more than one layout of the forms, not knowing which form (pdf) layout is being uploaded.

Is it as simple as labelling the different layouts within the same model. Or is there another way to identify which model is to be used with which form.?

any help greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

This is a common request. for now, if the 2 forms styles are not that different, you could try to train one model and see if that model could correctly extract key/value.  Another option is to train two different forms, you could write a simple classification program to decide which model to use.

Form Recognizer team is working on a feature to allow user just submit the document and it would pick the most appropriate model to analyze the document.  Please stay tuned for our update.

thanks

Comment: Yeah, this is my problem. Adding different layouts in the same model seems to work. But is it the right way? Is there a better way to decide which trained model to use before analysing?

Comment: If the layouts are not that different,  you could certainly use one model to train them.  If they are completely different,  it implies they are for different purposes,  so they should be trained as different models.   As I mentioned before, you could do classification by yourself when you have many models.

Comment: @XinZou any update on this feature? Or can you tell me if it is tracked somewhere where I can look?

Comment: yes, it's available.  the feature is called 'model compose',  please check https://github.com/microsoft/OCR-Form-Tools/wiki/Model-Compose